# PerformSegueWithIdentifier() takes noticeable longer when it is performed the first time after launching the app

Tags: ios, swift

I am calling `PerformSegueWithIdentifier()` to show a second `UIViewController` when a cell in a `UITableView` is selected. The problem is that when a cell gets selected the first time after the app was launched the segue takes noticable longer (maybe around 1 second) than normally. The second time, third time and so an a cell gets selected the segue is performed immediately. After restarting the app the first segue after a cell gets selected takes again much longer.

My Code is written in C# (Xamarin.IOS) but it is principally the same in Swift:

```
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
        {
            ShopVC.PerformSegue("DetailSegue", tableView.CellAt(indexPath));
        });
```

As you can see I have already searched for a solution an come up with this one to call the main thread but this doesn't solved my problem at all.

I would appreciate every suggestion. It is no problem when it will be written in Swift. I think it could help more people.

Comment: Why are you dispatching it on the main queue?  A table row selection will already be executing on the main queue.  You can use the Time Profiler instrument to see where your app is spending time

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that. I got this from other similar questions. 

The setup in `ViewDidLoad()` seems to take the time. I am creating the UI in the second `UIViewController` programmatically, could this slow down the process? But there is no hard work the app has to do. Just creating simple labels and textviews.